# Generating STL thumbnails in swift

Tags: swift, stl, scenekit, thumbnails

is it at all possible to generate thumbnails from imported stl files in my app?
I have a collection view for projects and I would like to generate a thumbnail for the new projects added. my app imports files of types stl (Standard Tesselated Geometry File Format) and .obj (Geometry Definition File Format)

Comment: Try to create an empty "placeholder" scene in SceneKit with lights and a camera. Then load the files into the scene with ModelO and create a snapshot of your `SCNView`.

Comment: @jlsiewert wouldn't that be incredibly inefficient in terms of memory

Comment: it would be resource intensive, but the a stl file only contains a list of vertices. If you want to generate an image you would need to import it into a 3D engine and render an image using the engine. However, when doing it only once while importing you should be fine, just store the thumbnail alongside your stl file.

Comment: @jlsiewert I ended up using SCNRenderer and took a snapshot. it supports all formats supported by ModelIO. I just have a question if you can rotate objects before snapshotting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO

private let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!

//MARK: thumbnail
/// Create a thumbnail image of the asset with the specified URL at the specified
/// animation time. Supports loading of .scn, .usd, .usdz, .obj, and .abc files,
/// and other formats supported by ModelIO.
/// - Parameters:
///     - url: The file URL of the asset.
///     - size: The size (in points) at which to render the asset.
///     - time: The animation time to which the asset should be advanced before snapshotting.

func thumbnail(for url: URL, size: CGSize, time: TimeInterval = 0) -> UIImage? {
    let renderer = SCNRenderer(device: device, options: [:])
    renderer.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    if (url.pathExtension == "scn") {
        let scene = try? SCNScene(url: url, options: nil)
        renderer.scene = scene
    } else {
        let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
        let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: asset)
        renderer.scene = scene
    }

    let image = renderer.snapshot(atTime: time, with: size, antialiasingMode: .multisampling4X)
    return image
}
```